# Regex match between Hugo tags

Tags: regex, hugo, re2

I have a Hugo tag that looks like this:

`{{< ref posts/filename >}}`

filename is a variable and is the bit I want to be left with.

So far I've got this:

`/\{\{\< (.*?) \>\}\}\)/`

Which leaves me with:

`ref posts/filename`

But I can't figure out how to remove the rest before the filename

Comment: By matching up to `/`? `/\{\{<[^>\/]*\/(.*?) >\}\}\)/`?

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much. If you want to post that as the answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I removed `\)` from the end of the pattern in the answer as you did not provide a sample input with a trailing round bracket.

Comment: Ah yes. Apologies. The whole thing should be wrapped in parenthesis, so my input actually looks like ({{< ref posts/filename >}}). We'll spotted. Your reply worked either way.

Edit: I was wrong. It's not wrapped in parenthesis. But your answer still worked after I've removed the closing \).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the check mark next to your comment. Could it be because I haven't earned enough points to accept an answer?

Comment: Mate - not sure if this helps, two times I regex'd in Hugo, 1 time I was brute forcing something with a MUCH better handling already built in into Hugo, second time it was valid, maybe, expand on what you are trying to do and we can see how Hugo already is built to handle it. Maybe not, but I'm willing to try to assist.

Comment: I'm using Obsidian to write with. One of advantages/reasons is the ease for making links between notes with wikilinks. Those 'other notes' will be articles in my website that I want to cross reference. I want to make it easier to reformat wikilinks as needed to work when publishing a Hugo post. So, I've made a plugin that will toggle between the wikilink format and Hugo format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match any chars other than `>` and `/` up to the first `/` from the `{{<` part:

```js
\{\{<[^>\/]*\/(.*?) >\}\}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NIClqb/1).

*Details*:

- `\{\{<` - a `{{<` substring
- `[^>\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `>` and `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `>\}\}` - a  `>}}` substring.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%7B%5C%7B%3C%5B%5E%3E%5C%2F%5D*%5C%2F(.*%3F)%20%3E%5C%7D%5C%7D):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\/)[^ ]*(?=[ >])
```

That leaves me with:

```
filename
```

Working example:
https://regex101.com/r/oSBW4q/1